# Iterator.remove() is not working while removing values from list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a list let say car and i have to remove the values from the list based on certain condition so if the value is null then i have to remove the value from the list.
My code looks like :

```
List<CarDTO> carList //list 
Iterator<CarDTO> itr = carList.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext())
{
    CarDTO car = itr.next();
    String carText = car.getCarText();
    carText = replaceCarTextWithCompanyName(carText, readData);
    if (CommonUtils.isEmpty(carText))
    {
        itr.remove();   //this is not working, values are still getting displayed
    }
    else
    {
        car.setCarText(carText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, please give a runnable example

Comment: Actually i need to set values based on a condition which i'm doing by making a function call, if the values is null from that fun() then we need to discard that value from it otherwise we need to set that value to be displayed on the frontend

Comment: Please give a runnable example

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Bob", "Don", null, "Mark", null, "John"));
    
    List<String> newNames = names.stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ;
    
    newNames.forEach(System.out::println);
```